# MathHelper.WrapAngle() rotation issue

Tags: c#, math, xna, trigonometry

My game involves ships moving and rotating around a target (i.e., an enemy ship). Rotation depends on whether the user wants to rotate by port/starboard, or just by the closest side to the enemy.

**The problem:**
The angles are being wrapped with `MathHelper.WrapAngle()`. Keeping the angles between PI and -PI works great, until the rotating ship gets to the point where -3.141 becomes 3.141 (and vice versa). For example, the ship is rotating to port correctly, then when it hits this line it flips over starboard, then back to port again, then starboard again and so on!

I would be very grateful if the community could point out:

1. What I can do to make the ship rotate logic work correctly when going over the PI/-PI wrap 'barrier'
2. Point out any inefficiencies in my code (I'm sure there are many, and I'm sure there are many other ways to do this more efficiently)
3. Link to any relevant articles or tutorials that can help me overcome this issue (this is my first game)

**Additional Information:**
`Ship.ShipMoveState.NoMoveRotate` is essentially a flag that tells the ship to rotate (starting at 100th of max speed up until we hit max speed) either port or starboard, whichever is closest. The ship rotates to these sides as that is where the weapons are located. `ShipMoveState.AwaitFurtherOrders` is tells the ship to rotate depending on the difference in angle between closest side (port/starboard) and angle to enemy.

```
ShipCompartment primeCompartment = TargetShip.CenterCompartment;
            if (FireState == ShipFireState.FireAtTarget)
                primeCompartment = TargetCompartment;

            // If ship is to the left of target, below will work
            Vector2 distanceToDestination = primeCompartment.Position - CenterCompartment.Position;
            float angleToEnemy = (float)Math.Atan2(distanceToDestination.Y, distanceToDestination.X);
            angleToEnemy = MathHelper.WrapAngle(angleToEnemy);

            CenterCompartment.Rotation = MathHelper.WrapAngle(CenterCompartment.Rotation);
            float portBatteryAngle = MathHelper.WrapAngle(CenterCompartment.Rotation - Helpers.RightAngle);
            float starboardBatteryAngle = MathHelper.WrapAngle(CenterCompartment.Rotation + Helpers.RightAngle);

            float allowance = 0.005f;
            bool portIsClosest = false;

            switch (primaryFacing)
            {
                case PreferredFacing.None:
                    // If port battery not facing enemy
                    if (angleToEnemy > (MathHelper.WrapAngle(portBatteryAngle + allowance))
                        || angleToEnemy < (MathHelper.WrapAngle(portBatteryAngle - allowance)))
                    {
                        // And starboard battery not facing either
                        if (angleToEnemy > (MathHelper.WrapAngle(starboardBatteryAngle + allowance))
                            || angleToEnemy < (MathHelper.WrapAngle(starboardBatteryAngle - allowance)))
                            MoveState = Ship.ShipMoveState.NoMoveRotate;
                        else
                            MoveState = ShipMoveState.AwaitFurtherOrders;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        portIsClosest = true;
                        MoveState = ShipMoveState.AwaitFurtherOrders;
                    }

                    if (MoveState == ShipMoveState.AwaitFurtherOrders)
                    {
                        float diff = 0f;

                        if (portIsClosest)
                            diff = angleToEnemy - portBatteryAngle;
                        else
                            diff = angleToEnemy - starboardBatteryAngle;

                        RotateShip(diff);
                    }
                    else if (MoveState == Ship.ShipMoveState.NoMoveRotate)
                    {
                        // Turn to port (if target is between 6 and 9 o'clock)
                        if (angleToEnemy < portBatteryAngle)
                            RotateShip(-MaxRotation / 100);
                        // Turn to starboard (if target is between 3 and 6 o'clock)
                        else if (angleToEnemy > starboardBatteryAngle)
                            RotateShip(MaxRotation / 100);
                        else
                        {
                            if (angleToEnemy > portBatteryAngle && angleToEnemy < starboardBatteryAngle)
                            {
                                // Turn to starboard (if target is between 9 and 12 o'clock)
                                if (angleToEnemy < CenterCompartment.Rotation)
                                    RotateShip(MaxRotation / 100);
                                // Turn to port (if target is between 12 and 3 o'clock)
                                else
                                    RotateShip(-MaxRotation / 100);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

Please let me know if you require any further information. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of, for instance,

```
a < wrap(b-c)
```

use

```
0 < wrap(b-c-a)
```

or

```
0 > wrap(a-b+c)
```

This makes it a little less readable, but is the correct way to compare (supposedly small) angle differences.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Do you know of a way to compensate for 'a' when 'a' changes from -3.141 to 3.141?

Comment: It should not matter, because it is just another measure for the same angle. The wrapAngle procedure should automatically compensate, it should always give `wrap(-PI+b)==wrap(PI+b)`.

Comment: OK, clearly my logic is at fault rather than my use of WrapAngle(). I'll need to keep working on this. Thanks @LutzL for your help.